# flask update database based on value sent from jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I am making shopping cart page using flask and jquery, flask send data to jquery, and jquery generate a table based on the data, each table row has an input field that has quantity in it, when ever the user click on the update button the jquery gets the value and send it to flask to process, however I flask return the value sent as None, I am not sure what is the problem, is it jquert post data or flask get data.

Table

```
$.ajax({
    url: '%%url_for("shopping_cart.get")%%%%process_query_string(request)%%',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json', // added data type
    success: function (res) {
        var grand_total = 0;

        $.each(res, function (key, value) {
            var product = value.id;
            var qty = value.Number_of_item;
            var price = value.Price;
            var tot = price * qty;
            var markup = "<tr>"
                + "<td class='width-10'><a href='#' class='remove-item' ><i id = '" + product + "' class='fa fa-times-circle'></i></a></td>"
                + "<td>" + product + "</td>"
                + "<td class='width-50 center' id = 'price" + product + "'  >" + price + "</td>"
                + "<td class='qty-txt-box'><input name='quanitity' type='text' id = 'qty" + product + "' class = 'quantity' value='" + qty + "'><i  class='fa fa-refresh'></i></td>"
                + "<td class='width-50 center' ><div id = 'total" + product + "' class = 'total' >$" + tot + "</div></td>"
                + "</tr>";

            grand_total = grand_total + tot;
            $('#yourID').append(markup);
        });
        $('#total').html("$" + grand_total);
    }
});
```

script to update button

```
$('#update').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jsonObj = [];
    var qty;
    url = "/shopping_cart/update";
    $(".quantity").each(function (e) {// get value of inputs fields
        qty = $(this).val();
        jsonObj.push(qty);
    });
    console.log(jsonObj);
    data = {'quantity': jsonObj};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        datatype: ' json',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            error = "";
            for (key in err.responseJSON) {
                error += err.responseJSON[key] + "<br>";
            }
            if (error)
                $("#error p").html("<p>" + error + "</p>");
            else
                $("#error p").html("<p>" + err.responseText + "</p>");
            $("#error").show();
        }
    });
});
```

flask update route

```
@shopping_cart.route("/shopping_cart/update", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def update():
    data = request.args.get('quanitity')
    print(data)
    '''return None I tried data = request.args.getlist('quanitity')
    data = request.get_json()
    data = request.json'''
    return jsonify({'message': 'done'})
```

I want to print the value so I can update the table in sqlAlchemy, but I keep getting None value. any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to give a value to your text input _name_ attribute `<input name="quantity" …`. The string will be used to identify the input value within the request payload server-side whatever the method in use `request.whatever.get(FIELD_NAME)`. Not giving a name makes the input's value to not be sent at all.

Comment: I updated my question still return None

Comment: "quanitity" is not equal to "qaunitity"

Comment: my bad I fixed the typo, but now I get POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/shopping_cart/update 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Comment: [HTTP 400 status: the server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error, (e.g., malformed request syntax, size too large, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Since this has now nothing to do with your original problem (missing input _name_ attribute and typo error), you might need to post another question if you still struggle to solve your new issue.

Answer (score 0):

You use `POST` method to send request, and get param from `args`.

This need get param from `form`.

Just like:

```
data = request.form.get('qaunitity')
print(data)
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to get `form` list data. you should use as follows:

```
data = request.form.getlist('quantity[]')
print(data)
```

Comment: I have tried that, but I get none when I print(data)

Comment: thank you for replying, I tried that, now it return empty array []

Comment: Before send post. what the console log show the data value? I just do a test. I have get the whole list value.

Comment: It shows the value in the input like this (2) ["2", "1"] 0: "2" 1: "1"

Comment: Ok. Now you add `print(request.form)` below the `print(data)`. Check the flask output. For my test. It show `ImmutableMultiDict([('quantity[]', '1'), ('quantity[]', '2')])`.

Comment: it return ImmutableMultiDict([]), I think the problem is in the post request,

Comment: I think you should use smallest tests for your code. And check the console and flask output. And have you get some error output?